# Can WriteProcessMemory fail but report that it didn't?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I'm trying to use [Rust's Windows WriteProcessMemory](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Diagnostics/Debug/fn.WriteProcessMemory.html) in a [project of mine](https://github.com/kmanc/remote_code_oxidation/blob/process_hollowing/process_hollowing/src/rco_process_hollowing_windows/mod.rs#L96) in order to replicate the process hollowing technique. Although I use it in nearly exactly the same way [in another place in the project](https://github.com/kmanc/remote_code_oxidation/blob/process_hollowing/process_migration/src/rco_process_migration_windows/mod.rs#L55), I'm having trouble getting this one to work. It looks to me like the whole buffer isn't getting copied to the location I enter, and/or the u8 integers are being squished into u64s when written.

The WriteProcessMemory call returns BOOL(1), which evaluates to true, and makes me think it is running successfully. If I provide the lpnumberofbyteswritten variable, it comes back as the same size as the shellcode buffer I intended to write. But the memory doesn't look right if I read it after writing, and the shellcode doesn't run properly (whereas in the other place in my project it does). Have I made a silly mistake? If so, does anyone see where?

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you are writing to where you think you are?

Comment: I think so, but the more I look into things the less I feel I understand lol. I re-ran the process migration code with some extra debugging so I could inspect memory after the WriteProcessMemory, and it actually looks identical to the process hollowing code at that point (which is different from what it looks like when you inspect it in C# but that's fine). This makes me think that ResumeThread is the issue, but that seems to run fine. I know the shellcode can work as it's the same shellcode so I'm back to the drawing board